# Can Ubuntu translate an App to English

Tags: language-support

I apologise if this is a stupid question

I installed an App called Love Wallpaper HD from [here](http://www.lovebizhi.com/linux.html) using the .deb download

[image]

As you can see it's Chinese. I can't seem to find an English language version.

Is there a way to translate so it displays in English. Although it's not essential to make the programme usable as it's fairly self explanatory, it would be nice as it's a wonderful programme.

Running Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

The window title:

```
class LoveWallpaper(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, app=None):
        super(LoveWallpaper, self).__init__(parent)
        #Set app title
        self.app = app
        self.setWindowTitle(u"爱壁纸HD")
```

There is also a

```
 self.searchLine.setPlaceholderText(u"搜索")
```

Hardcoded it seems...

Also note that there is already a language file for the desktop launcher:  https://gitcafe.com/LoveWallpaper/LoveWallpaperHD-Linux/blob/master/lovewallpaper/love-wallpaper.desktop

For british it includes:

```
Keywords[en_GB]=Wallpaper;Screen;Desktop;
```

Might be worth to include the language it uses (if not already there). It might be due to there not being a [us] in there! :D

Since it is a **commercial application** the answer will be: no we can not. Be careful to not violate their license (maybe start by mailing the owner and ask if they can do it for you or if not you can do it for them and then send them thee things you altered): https://gitcafe.com/LoveWallpaper/LoveWallpaperHD-Linux/blob/master/COPYING You may copy, share and use it. Nothing about altering it ;)